# return_counts=True not returning right count

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, 3d

I am trying to save masks which contain label [0,1,2] using the code:

```
for img in range(len(t2_list)):   #Using t1_list as all lists are of same size
    print("Now preparing image and masks number: ", img)
      
    temp_image_t2=nib.load(t2_list[img]).get_fdata()
    temp_image_t2=scaler.fit_transform(temp_image_t2.reshape(-1, temp_image_t2.shape[-1])).reshape(temp_image_t2.shape)
   
    
        
    temp_mask=nib.load(mask_list[img]).get_fdata()
    temp_mask=temp_mask.astype(np.uint8)

    print(np.unique(temp_mask))
    val, counts = np.unique(temp_mask, return_counts=True)
    
    if (1 - (counts[0]/counts.sum())) > 0.01:  #At least 1% useful volume with labels that are not 0
      print("Save Me")
      temp_mask= to_categorical(temp_mask, num_classes=2)
      np.save('/content/drive/MyDrive/input_data_3channels/images/image_'+str(img)+'.npy', temp_combined_images)
      np.save('/content/drive/MyDrive/input_data_3channels/masks/mask_'+str(img)+'.npy', temp_mask)
    else:
      print("nope”)
```

This results in nope even if the array contain [0 1 2] how can I fix this :

Now preparing image and masks number:  20
[0 1]
nope
Now preparing image and masks number:  21
[0 1]
nope
Now preparing image and masks number:  22
[0 1]
nope
Now preparing image and masks number:  23
[0 1]
nope
Now preparing image and masks number:  24
[0 1]
nope
Now preparing image and masks number:  25
[0 1]
nope
Now preparing image and masks number:  26
[0 1 2]
nope
Now preparing image and masks number:  27
[0 1]
nope
Now preparing image and masks number:  28

Answer (score 1):

The issue was resolved by changing the val, counts = np.unique(temp_mask, return_counts=True) to :

val, counts = np.unique((np.unique(temp_mask)), return_counts=True)